# lodash throttle function doesn't seem to be called

Tags: javascript, api, lodash, throttling

I'm using lodash's `throttle` function for the first time to try and throttle the number of calls to an API, however in my attempts I can't seem to get it to trigger a call.

I have included a simplified version below:

```
const _ = require('lodash');

let attempts = 0;

const incrementAttempts = () => {
  console.log('incrementing attempts');
  attempts++;
  console.log("attempts now: " + attempts);
}

const throttledAttempts = () => { 
  // From my understanding, this will throttle calls to increasedAttempts to one call every 500 ms
  _.throttle(incrementAttempts(), 500); 
}

// We should make 5 attempts at the call
while(attempts < 5) {
  throttledAttempts();
}
```

This initially gave me the output:

```
incrementing attempts
attempts now: 1
TypeError: Expected a function
    at Function.throttle (/home/runner/SimilarUtterUnits/node_modules/lodash/lodash.js:10970:15)
```

After looking up this error I saw a suggestion to add an anonymous wrapper to the `throttle` function, so now my `throttledAttempts` looks like:

```
const throttledAttempts = () => { 
  _.throttle(() => incrementAttempts(), 500); 
}
```

However doing this... I now get **NO** console output whatsoever!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `incrementAttempts()` calls `incrementAttempts`, and passes `undefined` to `_.throttle`, because `incrementAttempts` doesn't return anything.

Comment: it should be `_.throttle(incrementAttempts, 500)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `_.throttle` returns the new throttled function. Your code should be something like:

```
let attempts = 0;

const incrementAttempts = () => {
  console.log('incrementing attempts');
  attempts++;
  console.log("attempts now: " + attempts);
}

const throttledAttempts = _.throttle(incrementAttempts, 500);

// We should make 5 attempts at the call
while(attempts < 5) {
  throttledAttempts();
}
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks for pointing that out! Some of the guides I'd been reading didn't explicitly point that out that I'd seen. Big help!